# initramfs - Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: system-installation

I'm desperately trying to install ubuntu 12.10 64bit on my new Ultrabook.
Its a Sony T13 with 8gb ram, 256gb ssd, i7, windows 8.

- I have an extra partition, D: "UBUNTU" already created with about 30gb space using FAT32.
- Ubuntu is MD5 checked, on a previously working USB stick using UNetBootin.
- Grub loads fine
- When I ask to test out Ubuntu ("Try ubuntu without installing") it shows the purple loading screen for a bit then brings up this error in a busybox terminal:

`initramfs - Unable to find a medium containing a live file system`

**Things I've tried that don't work:**

- Different versions of Linux (Fedora, Arch, SL, even gParted)
- Using USB2/3 - No difference
- Legacy or UEFI - different interface, but same error
- BIOS has no option for anything "ACHI" related

I have read through tons of other people having this problem and diligently tried all the above solutions, with no luck.

Comment: Fixed! Here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/277611/initramfs-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system
(have invited this user to post answer)

Comment: The link in your comment points back to this page. Could you please fix this and post the actual link to the solution that worked for you? Thanks.

Comment: Yup, sorry will do as soon as Ubuntuforums is back online :) *eatingpopcorn.jpg*

Comment: Coming to think of it, it might actually be a better idea to write a new answer with the information from the forum, so that people can access the solution even when the external site is down. Also, that way there would be something you can tick off as correct. What do you think?

Comment: FYI, the forums are back online.

Comment: No luck fixing the link?

Comment: running into the same issue, any chance we could get a link to the solution?

Comment: May be [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1850520)

Answer (score 0):

Your situation may be different, but I was trying to install using a DVD in an IDE DVD-ROM drive onto an IDE HD.  The unlikely solution for me was to change the jumpers on the back of both drives to where the DVD-ROM drive was the master and the HD was the slave (both were previously set to be assigned by BIOS).  Again, worked for me, hope it works for you.  Took me a week of pulling my hair out to figure it out.

Comment: The OP says he has an *Ultrabook* that comes with an *SSD* (UEFI and all the other new stuff). You talk about IDE jumper settings and give instructions which may void the warranty. Please be a little more careful.

Answer (score -1):

Try this ...

Hit delete to run setup and confirm if in the bios or somewhere (...) you don't have one option to boot with windows ... if you find it change it to others ...

It worked with me ... it solved that problem ... and i lost one hour reading foruns trying to find out one solution for that ... and the solution was as simple as that ...

Regards,
Carlos